# Redirect to one model to another model by clicking a sumit button with a querystring in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to redirect view page to another view page by cliecking button of viewpage.
Ex,

I have two Pages
   1. Student
   2. BookIssue

I have to filter StudentName.  In this viewPage I have one textbox and one submit button.  When i click on Submit button it should take me to BookIssue Controller with studentName which was entered in textbox.

I have to TempData to get the value in another model But I Thinks not the good practice to use this in the code

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try `RedirectToAction` result with `studentName` in rout parameters

```
public ActionResult Student(string studentName)
{
    //...
    return RedirectToAction("index", "BookIssue", new { studentName });
}
```

Then receive `studentName` in `BookIssueController`.

Also you can redirect by typing `action` name and `controller` name in form of student page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "BookIssue"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("StudentName")
    <input type="submit" name="Go to Book Issue"/>
}
```